# To solve integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

> Let $\phi : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\phi (0) =0$.
>   If $(\phi (t))^{2} \leq 2 + \int _{0}^{t} \phi (s) ds  \ \ \ \forall t \geq 0$ then what is $\phi ( \sqrt{2})$?

I tried using derivative but it didn't help me much.Can anyone please suggest me how to start?

Comment: Certainly $\phi=0$ satisfies the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are some obvious solutions to $\phi(t)^2\leq 2+\int_0^t\phi$ such as the trivial solution $\phi=0$ or $\phi(t)=\min(t,1)$.  So $\varphi(\sqrt{2})$ cannot be determined.

However, you can bound $\phi(\sqrt{2})$, e.g., $\phi(2)\leq(1+\sqrt5)/\sqrt2$.  Note that $\psi(t)=\sup_{[0,t]}\phi$ also satisfies the integral inequality, and we have $\int_0^t\psi\leq\psi(t)t$.  So $\psi(\sqrt{2})^2\leq 2+\sqrt{2}\psi(\sqrt{2})$ giving the bound above.